# How can you normalize two data sets to the same scale?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have two data sets, one that ranges from 0-200, and another that ranges from ~400-~2500.

I would like to compare the two according to a score from 0-10. I remember about normalizing from a statistics class that I took that in order to normalize you need to find the z-score which depends on the population mean and standard deviation (which I have). But I don't remember what to do with that z-score, or how to normalize both of these data sets down to a 0-10 scale so that they can be scaled down and compared against each other.

Anyone remember how to do this?

Comment: If you have z-scores do you mean that you have both in standard normal form? You could then simply design some scale from 0-10 that depends on z scores

Comment: I'd like to get both distributions in standard normal form. But by z score, I took (random variable - mean)/stddev from the original data set. I'd like to know how to scale it down to standard normal form.

Comment: The right approach depends on *why* you want the score to run from $0$ to $10$. If you intend this score to be proportional to a quantile, you'll need $10\Phi(z)$, with $\Phi$ the $N(0,\,1)$ cdf.

Answer (score 1):

The z-score is the standardisation that you should plot.  Full-stop.  (And you have the correct formula for the z-score.)  The z-score might usually range from -3 to +3 and you can then plot both z-score distributions on the same graph.  The z-score distributions plot with their centres at z=0.  You mention you want to plot on a 0-10 scale.  What do you mean by this ?